# InnoSetup - Shortcut Icon on desktop corrupted

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Shortcuts from start menu and allprograms dir are fine but on the desktop shortcut is completely blank/corrupted?

```
#define MyAppName "MyAppName "
#define MyAppVersion "1"
#define MyAppPublisher "MyAppName"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.MyAppName.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyAppName.exe"


[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId=***
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=C:\***\{#MyAppVersion}
OutputBaseFilename=myapp_{#MyAppVersion}
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\***.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\***\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "***\bin\vcredist_x86.exe"; DestDir: {app}\bin\;
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}" 
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}" 
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{group}\Manual"; Filename: "{app}\Manual.pdf"


[Run]
Filename: {app}\bin\vcredist_x86.exe; Parameters: "/q:a /c:""VCREDI~3.EXE /q:a /c:""""msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn"""" """; WorkingDir: {app}\bin; StatusMsg: Installing Visual Studio 2010 C++ CRT Libraries...
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function GetUninstallString(): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function IsUpgrade(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString() <> '');
end;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function UnInstallOldVersion(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
// Return Values:
// 1 - uninstall string is empty
// 2 - error executing the UnInstallString
// 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString

  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssInstall) then
  begin
    if (IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      UnInstallOldVersion();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I really wonder why was this question downvoted, maybe the viewer who did it could enlighten me

Comment: Maybe he was looking for more detail, like the script code that is creating the corrupted shortcut.  Asking for that is a better way to get it rather than just downvoting, though.

Comment: it sure is more productive to suggest that, thanks Brad Stowers

Comment: Your script is fairly standard. What is in the lnk file itself? Does /log reveal anything?

Comment: Does it happen consistently on every machine you try it on, regardless of OS version?  If you right click the "corrupted" desktop shortcut and open its properties dialog, does it look correct there?  That is, does the target correctly point to your EXE, can you set an icon with the Change Icon button, etc?  As Deanna suggested, install it with /log and see if anything odd shows up in there.  Also, maybe try replacing {commondesktop} with {userdesktop} to see if that changes anything.

Comment: this is really weird, tried it on another machine and it looks fine, also looks fine here but only if i view shortcut from windows explorer. from desktop it looks bad and thats it

Comment: When you say it looks ok in Windows Explorer, do you mean when you look at the common user desktop folder location in Explorer?  That is, you are looking at exactly the same shortcut file, and when you look at in in an Explorer window it looks OK, but when you look at it on the desktop it doesn't look right?

Comment: On the problem system, are you using any special utilities that modify how the desktop appears or behaves?  If you start it up in Safe Mode, does it look correct then?  Have you changed the desktop properties to use an icon size that is something other than the normal 32x32?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that issue was icon which was 16x16 and 32x32 only, above that shows fine on desktop
was using win7